# How to determine if a number is positive or negative?

Tags: java, numbers

I was asked in an interview, how to determine whether a number is positive or negative. The rules are that we should not use relational operators such as `<`, and `>`, built in java functions (like `substring`, `indexOf`, `charAt`, and `startsWith`), no regex, or API's.

I did some homework on this and the code is given below, but it only works for integer type. But they asked me to write a generic code that works for `float`, `double`, and `long`.

```
 // This might not be better way!!

 S.O.P ((( number >> 31 ) & 1) == 1 ? "- ve number " : "+ve number );
```

any ideas from your side?

Comment: If there is a way to convert [whatever] to an array of bits, you could look at the most-significant-bit to determine whether or not the number is positive/negative...  Out of curiosity, how would a skill like this help you?  I haven't had a job yet but... it seems weird that they would take away basic operators from you :P

Comment: stupid contrived interview question

Comment: @ItzWarty  "how would a skill like this help you? " , the curiosity is because ,after having 5 yrs experience in j2ee (i was interviewed for java position and certainly did not expect this question from them :( ) , i felt bad of not able to give solution having CS background

Comment: @Mitch :) thanks , i hope the interviewer would be looking at this question.

Comment: I don't think they'd let you use the ternary operator if you cannot use an if statement ... your statement is no different than using an if/else.

Comment: @Mitch et al - the reason people ask questions like this is to try to see how good you are at figuring out novel solutions to tricky problems.  The problem is contrived, but they are more interested in the way you approach the problem than whether you get the right answer.

Comment: @Stephen C: I understand the reason. Companies like Google, Microsoft etc learned that these weren't the 'right' sort of interview questions many years ago...

Comment: @Mitch Wheat, I feel that these questions are sort of like asking the person you are interviewing to "Rearrange these sticks, which are in the formation of a camel, to draw the Loch Ness monster"...  Sure, they show that the person is able to think "out of the box"... but where in real life [or work, rather] is this useful?

Comment: Something that might help you brainstorm: http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CopyIntegerSign  ...  The sizeof operator is always used there, though, and Java [afaik] doesn't have anything like this =/

Comment: Are Java numbers always signed?  If so, can't you just convert the number to bytes and get the signed bit?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Itzwarty thanks for the link.But in title it says Integer.

Comment: @Dalin, that would require the use of an API, though [conversion from integer to 4 bytes].  Also, afaik, you can't do anything like *(byte*)(intptr) to get the most significant byte...  Note that the logic has to work for both 32-bit and 64-bit data types =/

Comment: What the input is? char[], string, int, or else ??

Comment: however, the question of the interviewer was not precise enough. quote: "we should not use conditional operators". this "==" is also a conditional operator. So it is not possible to answer this question at all. the two operators in brackets (<,>) are not a proper explanation at all. The interviewer must have used words to precise his meaning, like: "Regarding conditional operators You are only allowed to use the == operator". To investigate unprecise questions is *the skill* that is really needed in programmers-life.

Comment: Interviewer: "I've seen this neat trick in Java yesterday. I want you to read my mind and perform it for me. Can't do that, huh? Huh?" Hypothetical me as the applicant: [runs away].

Comment: It's a particularly stupid question in Java. C or C++, maybe. But not in Java.  If it is solvable without bit fiddling, then it's a math problem, and language is irrelevant.

Comment: @Suresh, pick one answer if you think it is time to close the question. That's how it worked around here, you know :)

Comment: `boolean isPositiveOrNegative(double number) { return number != 0; }`

Comment: Translated, the question would be *how would you go about reinventing the wheel? mind you, it has to be in a very contrived way!*

Comment: @SureshSankar : I understand ! I have been to the same office for an interview for a java position as well. The Geeks over there do not seem like they are hiring. They seem like to be in " I know the answer to a really tough question. let me see if you know that?." kind of mentality.If you got the answer to such a question,they say,"Have you seen this question already in the internet?".And if you dont,"You have to brush up your basics. Keep trying . Better luck next time".  Any way irrelevent cosnspicuous questions make up an interview ;) Cheers man ;)

Comment: Bear in mind that the solutions below *are for Java*. Other languages have different and often trickier (such as the case of C, C++, or JavaScript) rules.

Comment: @OlimilOops Regarding _...this "==" is also a conditional operator..._, it isn't; "==" is a **relational** operator, as are `<` and `>`. The question had been wrong for 10 years by incorrectly stating _"we should not use **conditional** operators such as `<`, and `>`"_.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The integer cases are easy. The double case is trickier, until you remember about infinities.

Note: If you consider the double constants "part of the api", you can replace them with overflowing expressions like `1E308 * 2`.

```
int sign(int i) {
    if (i == 0) return 0;
    if (i >> 31 != 0) return -1;
    return +1;
}
int sign(long i) {
    if (i == 0) return 0;
    if (i >> 63 != 0) return -1;
    return +1;
}
int sign(double f) {
    if (f != f) throw new IllegalArgumentException("NaN");
    if (f == 0) return 0;
    f *= Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    if (f == Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY) return +1;
    if (f == Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY) return -1;

    //this should never be reached, but I've been wrong before...
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unfathomed double");
}
```

Comment: the double solution is very clever/slick

Comment: Based on prior comments on other answers,  We could say the Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY  is part of the API. I do like it.  Could be made complete generic via a (double) cast.

Comment: I like the double solution too!  However, the first two methods should return boolean to compile.

Comment: @unhillbilly Whoops. I didn't run the int methods through an actual compiler. Fixed now.

Comment: @chris There's a note that the named double constants can be replaced with literal expressions. I'm not killing the clarity unless it's necessary.

Comment: @David It checks if the sign bit is set or not, by shifting it from the highest bit position (31) to the lowest bit position (0). See the [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation and [logical shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_shift) operation articles on wikipedia for more information.

Comment: Oh so you're shifting by 31 because integers are 32 bit?

Comment: You use the conditional operators == and != which are not allowed in the question.

Comment: @kirdie It's clear from the context of the question that == and != are allowed. The example solution from the question even includes one. I have no idea how you'd do it without them, either, since there don't seem to be any floating point operations that can turn Double.PositiveInfinity into a finite positive value (like the result of 1 you need in that case).

Comment: This is very helpful thanks. This tells me that I shouldn't not be using ">0" and "<0".

Comment: I don't understand this line: `if (f != f) throw new IllegalArgumentException("NaN");`, why isn't this always false? Can someone explain please? Thanks.

Comment: @Nom1fan https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Comparison_with_NaN

Answer (score 36):

The following is a terrible approach that would get you fired at any job...

It depends on you getting a Stack Overflow Exception [or whatever Java calls it]...  And it would only work for positive numbers that don't deviate from 0 like crazy.

Negative numbers are fine, since you would overflow to positive, and then get a stack overflow exception eventually [which would return false, or "yes, it is negative"]

```
Boolean isPositive<T>(T a)
{
  if(a == 0) return true;
  else
  {
    try
    {
      return isPositive(a-1);
    }catch(StackOverflowException e)
    {
      return false; //It went way down there and eventually went kaboom
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That one made ma laugh. :D

Comment: thanks, but it is like blowing a bomb and knowing the result.

Comment: What if number is `1.5` ,it won't result in 0 in any case directly, `0.5` and `-0.5` you should consider that also, otherwise nice idea:)

Comment: @Suresh S, did they say your code had to be "efficient"?;  @org.life.java: grah, you got me :P

Comment: @Suresh S @ItzWarty Check mine solution, no need to lighten up bomb :)

Comment: @ItzWarty  nothing on efficiency of code, but should work for higher numbers(scientific numbers),that's what he said and went out after giving this question:|.

Comment: This solution won't work for `1.5` or for any such real number

Comment: It won't work for 0.0001, will it?  Any number that is positive and non-integer that is...

Comment: you people know this http://img3.visualizeus.com/thumbs/09/02/04/code,review,illustration,wtf,b,w-ffde58dd8d68cad42fa1ea4309196e6d_h.jpg ? I'm like "Wtf is this shit?!" now.

Comment: Why would this throw a stack overflow? Wouldn't it just keep going with the recursion until it loops back to zero and returns true?

Comment: Hah, forgot this post existed. The call stack has a finite size. Imagine it's 1MB, for example. Heck, imagine it's 128MB (which is pretty huge). Then if you're counting upwards from, say, 1, until you reach 0, you're doing roughly 2^32 recursive calls, so even if each stack frame were 1 byte large (in reality they're certainly larger) you're certainly overflowing the stack.

Answer (score 17):

This will only works for everything except [0..2]

```
boolean isPositive = (n % (n - 1)) * n == n;
```

You can make a better solution like this (works except for [0..1])

```
boolean isPositive = ((n % (n - 0.5)) * n) / 0.5 == n;
```

You can get better precision by changing the 0.5 part with something like 2^m (m integer):

```
boolean isPositive = ((n % (n - 0.03125)) * n) / 0.03125 == n;
```

Comment: Pretty cool solution!  For the 0/1 you could cast to an integer and if it's equal to 0 or 1 then return true (or something like that).

Comment: Isn't == a conditional operator?

Comment: @billynomates: yes it is. However, looking at the answers, even the non valid answers, you practically don't have solution if you may not use it as well. It is after all not explicitly stated as part of the question

Answer (score 8):

You can do something like this:

```
((long) (num * 1E308 * 1E308) >> 63) == 0 ? "+ve" : "-ve"
```

The main idea here is that we cast to a long  and check the value of the most significant bit. As a double/float between -1 and 0 will round to zero when cast to a long, we multiply by large doubles so that a negative float/double will be less than -1. Two multiplications are required because of the existence of [subnormals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number) (it doesn't really need to be that big though).

Comment: @nanda Casting a double which is too large to a long will result in the largest representable value of type long as per the Java language specification (negatives behave the same way). Anyway, if num fits within a long, we're pretty much multiplying it to infinity anyway (with the exception of zero).

Comment: Since You have answered quickly for subnormal numbers , consider i accepted your answer.

Answer (score 6):

What about this?

```
return ((num + "").charAt(0) == '-');
```

Comment: Drats.  I don't have a java compiler handy, that's how you can do it in c#, thought maybe it would work here.

Comment: This would be a clever alternative to toString, and it follows the guidelines.  I'm not sure that Java allows this syntax, though.  C# and JavaScript will, though.  I love this logic, though.

Comment: Fixed to match java syntax. Nice solution :)

Comment: @Peter, is charAt considered part of the java API, though?

Comment: @ItzWarty: it is part of java.lang.String API, so probably yes.

Comment: Even `num + ""` translates to `sb = new StringBuilder(); sb.append(num); sb.append("")` ... is that java API usage or not? :)

Comment: it is simple with indexOf anyways cannot be used (num+"").indexOf("-") > 1

Comment: `java built in functions (like substring,indexOf,charAt,startsWith)`

Comment: @SureshSankar I think you mean (num+"").indexOf("-") == 0;  as it returns -1 if it is not in the string, and > 0 if it is not at the front of the string.

Answer (score 3):

```
// Returns 0 if positive, nonzero if negative
public long sign(long value) {
    return value & 0x8000000000000000L;
}
```

Call like:

```
long val1 = ...;
double val2 = ...;
float val3 = ...;
int val4 = ...;

sign((long) valN);
```

Casting from double / float / integer to long should preserve the sign, if not the actual value...

Comment: no API's Double.doubleToLongBits, why u are AND ing with 0x8000000000000000L , any significance on this number.

Comment: thanks, i think this answer is close ,i am testing ur code with 1E08 number. will let u know.

Comment: you are returning something and having void in method definition.

Answer (score 3):

You say

> we should not use conditional operators

But this is a trick requirement, because `==` is also a conditional operator.  There is also one built into `? :`, `while`, and `for` loops.  So nearly everyone has failed to provide an answer meeting all the requirements.

The only way to build a solution without a conditional operator is to use lookup table vs one of a few other people's solutions that can be boiled down to 0/1 or a character, before a conditional is met.

Here are the answers that I think might work vs a lookup table:

- Nabb
- Steven Schlansker
- Dennis Cheung
- Gary Rowe

Answer (score 2):

This solution uses modulus. And yes, it also works for `0.5` (tests are below, in the main method).

```
public class Num {

    public static int sign(long x) {
        if (x == 0L || x == 1L) return (int) x;
        return x == Long.MIN_VALUE || x % (x - 1L) == x ? -1 : 1;
    }

    public static int sign(double x) {
        if (x != x) throw new IllegalArgumentException("NaN");
        if (x == 0.d || x == 1.d) return (int) x;
        if (x == Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY) return 1;
        if (x == Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY) return -1;
        return x % (x - 1.d) == x ? -1 : 1;
    }

    public static int sign(int x) {
        return Num.sign((long)x);
    }

    public static int sign(float x) {
        return Num.sign((double)x);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        System.out.println(Num.sign(Integer.MAX_VALUE)); // 1
        System.out.println(Num.sign(1)); // 1
        System.out.println(Num.sign(0)); // 0
        System.out.println(Num.sign(-1)); // -1
        System.out.println(Num.sign(Integer.MIN_VALUE)); // -1

        System.out.println(Num.sign(Long.MAX_VALUE)); // 1
        System.out.println(Num.sign(1L)); // 1
        System.out.println(Num.sign(0L)); // 0
        System.out.println(Num.sign(-1L)); // -1
        System.out.println(Num.sign(Long.MIN_VALUE)); // -1

        System.out.println(Num.sign(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY)); // 1
        System.out.println(Num.sign(Double.MAX_VALUE)); // 1
        System.out.println(Num.sign(0.5d)); // 1
        System.out.println(Num.sign(0.d)); // 0
        System.out.println(Num.sign(-0.5d)); // -1
        System.out.println(Num.sign(Double.MIN_VALUE)); // -1
        System.out.println(Num.sign(Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY)); // -1

        System.out.println(Num.sign(Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY)); // 1
        System.out.println(Num.sign(Float.MAX_VALUE)); // 1
        System.out.println(Num.sign(0.5f)); // 1
        System.out.println(Num.sign(0.f)); // 0
        System.out.println(Num.sign(-0.5f)); // -1
        System.out.println(Num.sign(Float.MIN_VALUE)); // -1
        System.out.println(Num.sign(Float.NEGATIVE_INFINITY)); // -1
        System.out.println(Num.sign(Float.NaN)); // Throws an exception

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This code covers all cases and types:

```
public static boolean isNegative(Number number) {
    return (Double.doubleToLongBits(number.doubleValue()) & Long.MIN_VALUE) == Long.MIN_VALUE;
}
```

This method accepts any of the wrapper classes (`Integer`, `Long`, `Float` and `Double`) and thanks to auto-boxing any of the primitive numeric types (`int`, `long`, `float` and `double`) and simply checks it the high bit, which in all types is the sign bit, is set.

It returns `true` when passed any of:

- any negative `int`/`Integer`
- any negative `long`/`Long`
- any negative `float`/`Float`
- any negative `double`/`Double`
- `Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`
- `Float.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`

and `false` otherwise.

Comment: Very nice solution, a way to access the sign bit was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but illustrating my idea:

```
boolean IsNegative<T>(T v) {
  return (v & ((T)-1));
}
```

Comment: I think that should be (v & ((v) - 1))

Comment: I don't know much Java in this respect; but to make something 'generic' you can use Java generics - the templated argument so it should work on a variety of number widths; then, you want to see if the high bit is set (don't know which bit in a double or float gives the sign, reliably, but it can be worked out - does java support generic specialisations?).  So you take -1 as whatever the appropriate width is, and treat that as the high bit flag (there isn't a sizeof() in java iirc).  On reflection, I think this code would have to be much uglier to work.

Comment: Nice idea, but I think it will give you a compilation error.  You cannot cast to a type parameter.

Comment: Yeah, won't work at all. Java generics don't work with primitive tpyes, and arithmetic and bitwise operators don't work on wrapper types, and autounboxing again doesn't work generically.

Answer (score 1):

It seems arbitrary to me because I don't know how you would get the number as any type, but what about checking Abs(number) != number?  Maybe && number != 0

Answer (score 1):

Integers are trivial; this you already know. The deep problem is how to deal with floating-point values. At that point, you've got to know a bit more about how floating point values actually work.

The key is [Double.doubleToLongBits()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#doubleToLongBits%28double%29), which lets you get at the IEEE representation of the number. (The method's really a direct cast under the hood, with a bit of magic for dealing with NaN values.) Once a double has been converted to a long, you can just use 0x8000000000000000L as a mask to select the sign bit; if zero, the value is positive, and if one, it's negative.

Comment: And if they consider that to be an API, it's time to get your ass out of there and find an employer who isn't utterly retarded.

Comment: he he "it's time to get your ass out of there" nice quote.he said dont use API's.

Comment: Well, you can't do bitmagic in Java on floats or doubles without going through that particular needle (or something equivalent and nastier).

Comment: In particular, Java's *specified* to use round-to-zero when going from floating point to integer, so values like `-1e-20` will be deeply problematic (i.e., they convert to a value of the wrong sign). Math.floor would help, but that's prohibited. Stupid problem. Stupider company for asking it.

Answer (score 1):

one more option I could think of

```
private static boolean isPositive(Object numberObject) {
Long number = Long.valueOf(numberObject.toString());
return Math.sqrt((number * number)) != number;
}

 private static boolean isPositive(Object numberObject) {
Long number = Long.valueOf(numberObject.toString());
long signedLeftShifteredNumber = number << 1; // Signed left shift
long unsignedRightShifterNumber = signedLeftShifteredNumber >>> 1; // Unsigned right shift
return unsignedRightShifterNumber == number;
}
```

Comment: however, (number*number)^0.5 is not!

Comment: @Phoshi: operator ^ is not recognized in Java

Comment: @nanda; Oh. That blows this one out, then.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a valid answer

```
boolean IsNegative(char[] v) throws NullPointerException, ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException
{ 
  return v[0]=='-'; 
}
```

Comment: How do you get the char array without using String's toCharArray() method?

Comment: @Helper method: in this case, that's not the method's problem ;)

Comment: This is a great answer... Well, our input is not char[], that's the bad part :D

Answer (score 1):

This one is roughly based on ItzWarty's answer, but it runs in logn time! Caveat: Only works for integers.

```
Boolean isPositive(int a)
{
  if(a == -1) return false;
  if(a == 0) return false;
  if(a == 1) return true;
  return isPositive(a/2);
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you use casting to make this work for floating-point values?

Comment: Why is zero return false? Isn't zero a positive value?

Comment: @stakx - I don't think so. Imagine if I passed in 0.5...
@TEG - "Isn't zero a positive value?" Zero is not positive, it is non-negative.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a very simple solution:

```
public boolean isPositive(int|float|double|long i){
    return (((i-i)==0)? true : false);
}
```

tell me if I'm wrong!

Answer (score 1):

Try this without the code: `(x-SQRT(x^2))/(2*x)`

Answer (score 0):

Write it using the conditional then take a look at the assembly code generated.

Comment: they asked me to write the solution in java.anyway thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Why not get the square root of the number? If its negative - java will throw an error and we will handle it.

```
         try {
            d = Math.sqrt(THE_NUMBER);
         }
         catch ( ArithmeticException e ) {
            console.putln("Number is negative.");
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, taking advantage of casting (since we don't care what the actual value is) perhaps the following would work. Bear in mind that the actual implementations do not violate the API rules. I've edited this to make the method names a bit more obvious and in light of @chris' comment about the {-1,+1} problem domain. Essentially, this problem does not appear to solvable without recourse to API methods within Float or Double that reference the native bit structure of the float and double primitives.

As everybody else has said: Stupid interview question. Grr.

```
public class SignDemo {

  public static boolean isNegative(byte x) {
    return (( x >> 7 ) & 1) == 1;
  }

  public static boolean isNegative(short x) {
    return (( x >> 15 ) & 1) == 1;
  }

  public static boolean isNegative(int x) {
    return (( x >> 31 ) & 1) == 1;
  }

  public static boolean isNegative(long x) {
    return (( x >> 63 ) & 1) == 1;
  }

  public static boolean isNegative(float x) {
    return isNegative((int)x);
  }

  public static boolean isNegative(double x) {
    return isNegative((long)x);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {


    // byte
    System.out.printf("Byte %b%n",isNegative((byte)1));
    System.out.printf("Byte %b%n",isNegative((byte)-1));

    // short
    System.out.printf("Short %b%n",isNegative((short)1));
    System.out.printf("Short %b%n",isNegative((short)-1));

    // int
    System.out.printf("Int %b%n",isNegative(1));
    System.out.printf("Int %b%n",isNegative(-1));

    // long
    System.out.printf("Long %b%n",isNegative(1L));
    System.out.printf("Long %b%n",isNegative(-1L));

    // float
    System.out.printf("Float %b%n",isNegative(Float.MAX_VALUE));
    System.out.printf("Float %b%n",isNegative(Float.NEGATIVE_INFINITY));

    // double
    System.out.printf("Double %b%n",isNegative(Double.MAX_VALUE));
    System.out.printf("Double %b%n",isNegative(Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY));

    // interesting cases
    // This will fail because we can't get to the float bits without an API and
    // casting will round to zero
    System.out.printf("{-1,1} (fail) %b%n",isNegative(-0.5f));

  }

}
```

Comment: What about the domain:x in (-1,1)

Comment: Also, will your solution work for 64 bit machines? How is an `int` represented on 64 bit platform?

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman As I understand it, it's the JVM specification rather than the underlying hardware that defines the size of the various natives. But this may be different on 64-bit machines - I've not researched this. To be honest, the whole question is flawed since floating point cannot be covered.

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman You may want to review this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400477/on-a-64-bit-machine-is-the-size-of-an-int-in-java-32-bits-or-64-bits

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how exactly Java coerces numeric values, but the answer is pretty simple, if put in pseudocode (I leave the details to you):

```
sign(x) := (x == 0) ? 0 : (x/x)
```

Comment: @Manur: doh, you're right. Well, I'll leave it as an inspiration :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to use "==" as seems to be the case, you can do something like that taking advantage of the fact that an exception will be raised if an array index is out of bounds. The code is for double, but you can cast any numeric type to a double (here the eventual loss of precision would not be important at all).

I have added comments to explain the process (bring the value in ]-2.0; -1.0] union [1.0; 2.0[) and a small test driver as well.

```
class T {

   public static boolean positive(double f)
   {
       final boolean pos0[] = {true};
       final boolean posn[] = {false, true};

       if (f == 0.0)
           return true;

       while (true) {

           // If f is in ]-1.0; 1.0[, multiply it by 2 and restart.
           try {
               if (pos0[(int) f]) {
                   f *= 2.0;
                   continue;
               }
           } catch (Exception e) {
           }

           // If f is in ]-2.0; -1.0] U [1.0; 2.0[, return the proper answer.
           try {
               return posn[(int) ((f+1.5)/2)];
           } catch (Exception e) {
           }

           // f is outside ]-2.0; 2.0[, divide by 2 and restart.
           f /= 2.0;

       }

   }

   static void check(double f)
   {
       System.out.println(f + " -> " + positive(f));
   }

   public static void main(String args[])
   {
       for (double i = -10.0; i <= 10.0; i++)
           check(i);
       check(-1e24);
       check(-1e-24);
       check(1e-24);
       check(1e24);
   }
```

The output is:

```
-10.0 -> false
-9.0 -> false
-8.0 -> false
-7.0 -> false
-6.0 -> false
-5.0 -> false
-4.0 -> false
-3.0 -> false
-2.0 -> false
-1.0 -> false
0.0 -> true
1.0 -> true
2.0 -> true
3.0 -> true
4.0 -> true
5.0 -> true
6.0 -> true
7.0 -> true
8.0 -> true
9.0 -> true
10.0 -> true
-1.0E24 -> false
-1.0E-24 -> false
1.0E-24 -> true
1.0E24 -> true
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses no conditional operators, but relies on catching two excpetions.

A division error equates to the number originally being "negative". Alternatively, the number will eventually fall off the planet and throw a StackOverFlow exception if it is positive.

```
public static boolean isPositive( f)
       {
           int x;
           try {
               x = 1/((int)f + 1);
               return isPositive(x+1);
           } catch (StackOverFlow Error e) {
               return true;

           } catch (Zero Division Error e) {
               return false;
           }


   }
```

Comment: the while loop has a condition built in.

Comment: Thank you Merlyn for pointing that out. Even in my pseudo code I hate using recursive functions. Without the while loop, this would most likely have recursion depth issues.

Answer (score 0):

What about the following?

```
T sign(T x) {
    if(x==0) return 0;
    return x/Math.abs(x);
}
```

Should work for every type T...

Alternatively, one can define abs(x) as Math.sqrt(x*x),
and if that is also cheating, implement your own square root function...

Answer (score 0):

```
if (((Double)calcYourDouble()).toString().contains("-"))
        doThis();
else doThat();
```

Comment: If I was the interviewer, and the candidate started treating numbers as strings, that would be a red flag.  Of course, this is a stupid contrived interview question, so I suppose stupid 'clever' responses are appropriate.

Comment: Seeing the String is the mother of all information carriers/representation forms... (;

Answer (score 0):

Combined generics with double API. Guess it's a bit of cheating, but at least we need to write only one method:

```
static <T extends Number> boolean isNegative(T number)
{       
    return ((number.doubleValue() * Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY) == Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two simple solutions. Works also for infinities and numbers -1 <= r <= 1
Will return "positive" for NaNs.

```
String positiveOrNegative(double number){
    return (((int)(number/0.0))>>31 == 0)? "positive" : "negative";
}

String positiveOrNegative(double number){
    return (number==0 || ((int)(number-1.0))>>31==0)? "positive" : "negative";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a function is the math library called signnum.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/math_signum_float.htm
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/math_signum_double.htm

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to do this like

```
private static boolean isNeg(T l) {
        return (Math.abs(l-1)>Math.abs(l));
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
static boolean isNegative(double v) {
  return new Double(v).toString().startsWith("-");
}
```

Comment: @Suresh: Okay, [0] == '-'; then.

Comment: @Suresh S and rochal: you are right. I misunderstood the rules. I thought only conditional operators are not allowed.

Answer (score -2):

```
if(antennaHeight.compareTo(Double.valueOf(0))>=0)
```

In the above code,
`antennaHeight.compareTo(Double.valueOf(0))`  --- this 'll return int, comparing this with 0 gives the solution.

Answer (score -3):

> ```
> if (v < 0) System.out.println("negative"); else System.out.println("positive");
> ```

Comment: From the question: _"The rules are that we should not use conditional operators such as < and >"_