# Java Semaphor doesnt honour argument provided?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, semaphore

When I usesemaphor with 1 argument.
And then Release it twice, it increases available permits to 2 but ideally i have already mentioned that i want 1 lock. Now since i have 2 available permits two thread can acquire the lock which defeats the purpose of argument.

```
Semaphor lock = new Semaphor(1);
lock.release();
lock.release();

lock.acquire(); // thread1
lock.acquire(); //thread2
```

Why does it behave like that?

Comment: This code won't even compile. Please paste proper code in the question along with where you are getting the issue. Otherwise, the question might get downvoted

Answer (score 1):

> Why does it behave like that?

The [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) mentions it:

> When used in this way, the binary semaphore has the property (unlike
>   many Lock implementations), that the "lock" can be released by a
>   thread other than the owner (as semaphores have no notion of
>   ownership). **This can be useful in some specialized contexts, such as
>   deadlock recovery**.

---

You can use a [wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13960882/6690200) class to track the initial permit. But usually, it is not supposed to call `release` until the thread `aquire` the lock, so it should not become a problem.

Comment: But in multi threading app it is possible that release and acquire goes out of sync and it ends up calling release twice. May be i should use something else or write a wrapper. My question was had it been better if the semaphor were implemented that way where it should honour initial permit

Answer (score 0):

```
release()
```

From Oracle doc : Releases a permit, increasing the number of available permits by one. If any threads are trying to acquire a permit, then one is selected and given the permit that was just released. That thread is (re)enabled for thread scheduling purposes.

There is no requirement that a thread that releases a permit must have acquired that permit by calling acquire(). Correct usage of a semaphore is established by programming convention in the application.

Comment: I am not saying that the thread should have acquired but may be calling release multiple time shouldn't increase permit more that initial permit

Answer (score 0):

> Now since i have 2 available permits two thread can acquire the lock which defeats the purpose of argument.

It doesn't defeat the purpose of a `Semaphore`.  The purpose of `Semaphore` is to implement the counting semaphore abstraction as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)).

> Why `Semaphore` doesn't honor the argument provided?

It does honor it.  But the argument isn't a bound on the number of permits.  Rather it represents the number of permits that initially may be acquire without blocking.

> Why does it behave like that?

Because (in the opinion of the Java designers) that is the way that a counting semaphore *should* behave.

The standard `Semaphore` class does not have a way to restrict the number of permits.  If you want a lock (or a binary semaphore) you should use a `Lock` class ...

---

> But in multi threading app it is possible that release and acquire goes out of sync and it ends up calling release twice.

Yes.  That would be a bug in the application.

Now ... if you wanted to detect that, you could extend the `Semaphore` class and override the `acquire` and `release` methods to check that the number of permits stays between prescribed bounds.  (You could throw an unchecked exception if the check failed.  Or you could silently ignore the request ... though that sounds like a bad idea.)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation